# SQLite locked in a single thread, first transaction

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to replicate the schema from a DB2 database to a local sqlite database using sqlalchemy. Because of the restriction of the environment, I must do it using a jupyter notebook.

My code works fine when I create an in-memory sqlite database, but I get a 'database is locked' error from sqlite when I try to use a local file, like in the code below. I have trying shutting down all jupyter kernels and using a different file name for each run, but the error persists. It doesn't make sense that the database is locked, since I am running a single thread, with a single connection, and the create table statement is the first statement I ever submit to the database.

I also tried using SQLAlchemy to just compile the CREATE TABLE statement and then using sqlite3 package directly to explicily connect and execute it, buy I got exactly the same error, so I think the problem is not in SQLAlchemy. I am guessing it is something jupyter-specific?

I checked my file permissions and I have read, write and execute permission on the directory I am running the script. The database file is created, but it remains empty and I just get the error.

Anyone have an idea of how I could investigate this issue?

```py
import sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy.schema
from dbsetting import URL

db2_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(URL)
db2_meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
sqlite_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///test.sqlite')
print(sqlite_engine.table_names())

for table_name in db2_engine.table_names():
    table = sqlalchemy.Table(table_name, db2_meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=db2_engine)
    table.create(bind=sqlite_engine)
    break

print(sqlite_engine.table_names())
```

Comment: Is/was this issue highly reproducible for you? Was it always failing?