# Python SQLite database is locked in a single-thread interactive process despite closing all SQLAlchemy sessions/engines/connections

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

There are many SO questions with same issues. However, all other answers focus on user errors that are not valid for me.
In most other SO question, the situation involves 2+ process conflicting over the DB file. In my case, there is only a single process conflicting with itself. If you think about it, there is no reason why a single process cannot lose a file lock. Perhaps, SQLAlchemy or sqlite driver just creates a lock and forgets to ever release it.

My database file is on local internal HDD (not network).
I work from IPython/Jupyter environment on Windows via VSCode Interactive. There is just a single python.exe process. I do not use any viewers/consoles/apps that may access the DB. I do not use multi-threading. I have a single interactive session.
I have an sqlite database file. The file is FS-locked and cannot be moved. As per Process Explorer, the file is opened by a single python process which is the `python.exe` process running my ipykernel interactive session: `c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m ipykernel_launcher --ip=127.0.0.1 --stdin=9013 --control=9011 "--transport=\"tcp\"" --iopub=9014 --f=c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-xxx.json"`

I've tried calling `sqlite.orm.close_all_sessions()` and `engine.dispose()`. This does not unlock the file.

I can create engine/session and query the DB. But when I close all sessions and dispose the engine, the DB is still locked.

Today's lock has occurred when I tried to add index to the DB and it said "database is locked". It's been locked since then. DB was created via SQLAlchemy ORM with no fancy changes or features.

**How do I release the DB lock that my python.exe process is holding without killing the process?**

P.S. **Is there any way to list all Python objects in my process that own file locks?**

Comment: You will need to see if that's the process that's locking your file, see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3481134)

Comment: you are missing the code, but a lock means that a process tries to run a query and waits till the lock is cleared, so you must frst find he process that is locking and the rest woill resolve itself

Comment: @metatoaster I used Process Explorer to search for the the sqlite db file handle. It found the python.exe process holds the handle. BTW, NirSoft showed wrong information. It showed that the file was locked by a system process with a non-existing PID like 32000. So Process Explorer worked better for this.

Comment: @nbk There is only one process. And it's "me" (my IPython session). As I described in my question, I found the process. It's python.exe of my interactive session.  The process is basically c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m ipykernel_launcher --ip=127.0.0.1 --stdin=9013 --control=9011 "--transport=\"tcp\"" --iopub=9014 --f=c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-xxx.json" This does not solve my issue where I need to release the lock without killing that process. Is my explanation clear?

Comment: In most other SO question, the situation involves 2+ process conflicting over the DB file. In my case, there is a single process conflicting with itself. If you think about it, there is no reason why a single process cannot get into this state. It looks like, SQLAlchemy or sqlite driver just creates a lock and forgets to ever release it. I wonder how a file lock would look like in Python... I wonder whether the locking occurs in Python code or C code...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I unlock a SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat No. My question was how to remove the lock without killing my IPython process. I'm trying to solve the root cause, not just do "Turn it off, then on again".

Comment: @Ark-kun there are answers to that question that don't involve killing the locking process. In total there are **38 answers** to that question and quite a few of them don't involve killing the process that has the lock.

Comment: Might be a jupyter notebook specific issue, see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59259651/sqlite-locked-in-a-single-thread-first-transaction) but it has zero resolution.

Comment: so it is simpole your code sends two commands at the same time, somand 1 lock the table comand 2 waits till comand 1 has run its course, so the solution is simple the commands must be sequential and first command must be optimized

Comment: Question: Is your database file on a network folder? sqlite has trouble with locking files on the network. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6366752/14991864) Also see the 3rd paragraph in the section "6.0 How To Corrupt Your Database Files" of [this page](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html)

Comment: Getting additional information can be useful, even if it is not pointed toward your stated goal. Adding to @metatoaster's comment:  We found that the interactive Jupyter process was holding a database session open even when the code was not executing.  I am not familiar with IPython, as we use VSCode.  Is there a way to run python in IPython without an interactive Jupyter window for diagnostic purposes?

Comment: >"so it is simpole your code sends two commands at the same time. ... so the solution is simple the commands must be sequential" This cannot happen. I do not use threads. All my commands are sequential.

Comment: >"Question: Is your database file on a network folder?" No. It's on a local internal HDD.

Comment: To clarify regarding Jupyter vs IPython vs VSCode: I'm using VSCode interactive. It's a Jupyter-like environment. I do not know whether VSCode Interactive is built on top of Jupyter or not, but I know that both Jupyter and VSCode use IPython. So I said "IPython" in my question, because I technically don't use Jupyter.

Comment: >" Is there a way to run python in IPython without an interactive Jupyter window for diagnostic purposes?" You can just run IPython and you'll get a Jupyter-like environment, but in console. It even has auto-complete.

Comment: >"We found that the interactive Jupyter process was holding a database session open even when the code was not executing." Well, this makes sense. All the variables are alive including the session variable. However my problem is that even if I dispose the SQLAlchemy session and tell SQLAlchemy to close everything, something still lingers.

Comment: >"your code sends two commands at the same time, command 1 lock the table command 2 waits". This can technically happen even in a single thread with sequential commands. Command 1 locks the table and exits without unlocking. This is why I'm interested in understanding what exactly does it mean to "lock the table" in sqlite/SQLAlchemy/Python. What is a lock? Which variable holds the lock information?